# Is it possible to update CyanogenMod from within CyanogenMod?

Tags: htc-desire, cyanogenmod, updates

Is there a way to update CyanogenMod from within CyanogenMod without going though the whole flashing process? I'm looking a for one press update button.

Answer (score 4):

Depending on the version of CyanogenMod ROM you have currently installed, this can be easy or impossible.

If you already have CM7, and simply want to try out the nightly builds, [ROM Manager](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.koushikdutta.rommanager) and [ROM Manager Premium](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.koushikdutta.rommanager.license) unlock automate the entire process.  With a single button tap, it can download the latest version of the ROM, reboot to Recovery, take a backup of the current system, flash the new version, and reboot back.

If you are on an older version of CM (4/5/6) this cannot be done in one click, because of the drastic differences between the ROMs.  A full wipe of the device will be required, which means all of your settings and downloaded apps will be deleted, and will need to be re-installed manually (or in batch via [Titanium Backup](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.keramidas.TitaniumBackup) or [AppBrain](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.appspot.swisscodemonkeys.apps).)

Comment: ROM Manager asks to update to Premium. Is there a free alternative?

Comment: I don't know of any as advanced as RM.  The Premium upgrade is only necessary if you really want the full automation "one-click-upgrade" feature.